# When and why to insert Entity and its relational Entity references

Tags: entity-framework-6, logic, dbcontext, insert-update

i am building a function for a bulk import from a file and i am asking myself what i should do, i would like some feedback and maybe learn certain things for the future.

I have 3 Entities, lets call them E1, E2 & E3.

E1 has a property E2 and E2 has a property E3. I can build everything up (doing checks and so on) and insert E3, which will insert E1 & E2 (IF they don't already exist of course otherwise i would attach them).

But why shouldn't i for example build up E1 and insert it, continue build E2 and insert it, lastly build up E3 (with E1 & E2) and insert it ?

Is there a specific reason i shouldn't do that, to many calls maybe, is it a "no-go", ... ?

Kind regards!

Comment: It doesn’t matter wich Entity you add first to the Context. Important for performance is to call SaveChanges after all Entities are added. But for 3 Objects even this shouldn’t be much difference in performance.

Comment: @Nikolaus, thank you for your input, i editted the post, it is for a bulk operation (import) so it might be 3 entities but X amount of times. Hence the question i asked myself.

Comment: Anyone else has an opinion he would like to share on this?

Comment: Like I already said: Important is, that you call SaveChanges() after adding all Entities.

Comment: OK, i thought maybe there could be more to understand from this, you can elaborate this in an answer if you like, ill mark it as one. Thank you.

Comment: I did add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing is to call SaveChanges on the Context at the very end, when all entities are added. This way, all entities are inserted/updated in one Transaction and there are as few database-calls as possible.
The benefits are good performance and atomic-Transactions ( all succeeds or all fails).